# Custom Docker Image with Databricks jobs API

Tags: docker, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

Is there a way to create a temporary job cluster with a custom Docker image in Azure Databricks?
I can only find information on creating normal clusters with the Docker service.

My job definition json I want to send to the azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/jobs/create API looks like following:

```json
{
    "databricks_pool_name": "test",
    "job_settings": {
        "name": "job-test",
        "new_cluster": {
            "num_workers": 1,
            "spark_version": "7.3.x-scala2.12",
            "instance_pool_id": "<INSTANCE_POOL_PLACEHOLDER>",
            "docker_image": {
                "url": "<ACR_HOST_NAME>",
                "basic_auth": {
                    "username": "<ACR_USER>",
                    "password": "<ACR_TOKEN>"
                }
            }
        },
        "max_concurrent_runs": 1,
        "max_retries": 0,
        "schedule": {
            "quartz_cron_expression": "0 0 0 2 * ?",
            "timezone_id": "UTC"
        },
        "spark_python_task": {
            "python_file": "dbfs:/poc.py"
        },
        "timeout_seconds": 5400
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of your JSON is incorrect - if you look into [documentation for Jobs API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#create), you will see that you just need to send only content of your `job_settings` field:

```json
{
  "name": "job-test",
  "new_cluster": {
    "num_workers": 1,
    "spark_version": "7.3.x-scala2.12",
    "instance_pool_id": "<INSTANCE_POOL_PLACEHOLDER>",
    "docker_image": {
      "url": "<ACR_HOST_NAME>",
      "basic_auth": {
        "username": "<ACR_USER>",
        "password": "<ACR_TOKEN>"
      }
    }
  },
  "max_concurrent_runs": 1,
  "max_retries": 0,
  "schedule": {
    "quartz_cron_expression": "0 0 0 2 * ?",
    "timezone_id": "UTC"
  },
  "spark_python_task": {
    "python_file": "dbfs:/poc.py"
  },
  "timeout_seconds": 5400
}
```